Why does cutting a solenoid into half reduce its magntic properties
Cutting a solenoid is said to reduce its magnetic properties. Is this change attributed to its magnetic moment or to its magnetic field. Magnetic field of the solenoid could be same because the turn/length ratio remains constant but the magnetic moment of each would also be constant because nothing is changed.

The regions around the ends become more significant relative to the region around the middle.

Please clarify what you mean by "magnetic properties". The standard formula for the magnetic field of a finite solenoid is only valid at its midpoint.

Actually, it is due to neither its m.moment OR m.field.
Halving a solenoid, reduces the potential electromagnetic result by half. Think of it in terms of 'mass'.The 'Greater' the 'mass' of an object, the 'Greater' the potential capacity of such; in comparison to an  object of less.
In this case, the object is a Solenoid,
A converter of Energy as such.
The presence of Energy, is restricted by the capacity of the entity in which it exists. Therefore; 'cutting a solenoid in half' DEFINITELY reduces its 'Magnetic Properties' because 'Magnetic Properties'= Energy.
That's without mentioning the cellular wastage from environmental absorption.

As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers in the help center.
